# How to images resize when window resize?

Tags: css, resize, overlap

I have this site [My Site](http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/SISKOS/). If you try to resize the window you will see the image resizing. I want the page to work exactly as this one : [Template](http://apolosisk.wix.com/apostolos2)

I am tried with no result the min-width and text-wrap in the following code :

```
.wrapper-style1
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #eae5e5;
    min-width:70%; \\I changed that with some pixels but nothing changed. 

}
```

I tried to put some classes that inherit from .wrapper-style1 like : .wrapper-style1 a img and with minimum size and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to set a div to hold your elements and images. That div needs to have a fixed width (say 400px) to prevent all the elements getting squashed up together.

Comment: The div (class 4u) changes. Also I want the top navigation bar at the same alignment with the rest of the divs.